# iPhone and User Defined Runtime Attributes

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

What happened to "User Defined Runtime Attributes" under the Identity inspector in Interface Builder when building iPhone UIs?

I used to define a custom outlet for UITableView's tableHeaderView in versions before 3.1/3.2 or when it might have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you mean: In IB 3.2, open the Library Window (Command+Shift+L), select the Classes tab and select the class you want to add an outlet to from the dropdown list. Now there is an Outlets tab in the bottom section of the window with the option to add more outlets.